# authenticate individual users using api keys or public/private key pairs for api calls in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, security, authentication, django-rest-framework

i need to provide authentication method for my users so they can interact with my api endpoints out of the client side (frontend) . something like developer authentication . i've made research and realized that api keys are not recommended for authenticating individual users . on the other hand using ssh key pairs are good approach but saving private keys in order to decrypt the public key message is a security breach . all i need is just to understand the concept of implementing such authentication methods and the flow of how to do it.do you have any suggestion , advice or resource so i can figure out  how to implement it ?  Thanks

Comment: check https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/ and specially https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: nah i don't need jwt auth . what i need is HMAC authentication

Comment: Hey @atabakhooshangi i'm also searching for a good way of doing that. have u find a good solution? in my search, this two repos seems to be a way: https://github.com/backupbrain/drf-keypair-permissions https://github.com/florimondmanca/djangorestframework-api-key

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/django-hmac-authentication/